# IPython Copying all csv files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

```
!find ~/DataFolder/CSVfolders -name "*.csv" > paths.txt
```

My friend was using this command to get all the Comma separated values files directories into a text file, however, I have tired to manipulate it using the following

```
!find C:/directory/withdata -name "*.csv" > paths.txt
```

I am doing this in a Jupyter notebook, my first attempt had the folder outside of the jupyter notebook folder, and then I put it in the folder of the jupyter notebook, it keeps saying these two things.

Access Denied - ....

File not Found -name

I am kind of new to these bash shell commands in IPython setting, I also have a windows OS, any advice or sources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try opening the Jupyter notebook with admin rights.

Comment: @Krishna That's a *very* bad idea. Aside from violating the principle of least privilege, it probably wouldn't work because the Windows `find` command is interpreting "-name" as a (non-existent) file name. Access is denied because this non-existent file cannot be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Two solutions: PowerShell and Python

Your code is not working because you must use a Windows equivalent command to Unix `find`.
However, considering you are working with Python, a Python code could be a universal solution.

### The problem

By using the exclamation sign `!`, you are invoking the shell of your systems.
Thus, the command you execute is system dependent.

**Example**

```sh
# Change the name of file1 to file2 in Unix-like systems
# But it doesn't work on Windows
!mv file1 file2

# The Windows equivalent
!ren file1 file2
```

You have a similar problem. `Find` exists in both Unix-like and Windows; however, the purpose of both commands is different.
In Windows, [`find`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Windows)) command is a filter to find lines in the input data stream that contain or don't contain a specified string (i.e., it is like the `grep` command of Unix).

### The solution: with Windows PowerShell

After reading this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/401495) I propose the following solution using Windows PowerShell.

```
!Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.csv" -Recurse "C:/directory/withdata" > paths.txt
```

### The solution: with Python

Coming soon ... :)

Comment: Yes he was using a Linux system which I felt lost in but thanks. So manipulate to it to windows CMD

Comment: I updated my answer. Note that you cannot use `find` in Windows. The command has an entirely different purpose.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky, can you check the solution I posted works on Windows? Right now I have no access to a Windows PC

Comment: !dir  /b/s *.csv > paths.txt

Comment: this works too so I just look in the directory for all those files and shove them into a text document. Thanks for your help too, your os tip was helpful.